# AWS Cloudwatch Subscription Filter and Dead Letter Queue for Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using CloudWatch log subscription filters to get logs from a specific log group and send them to a Lambda function, which after processing will send the results to another service. I wonder if there's any possibility to send failed events by Lambda to a Dead Letter Queue, noting that in the above settings, we have no SNS/SQS setup to trigger the Lambda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Destinations gives you the ability to handle the Failure of function
> invocations along with their Success. When a function invocation
> fails, such as when retries are exhausted or the event age has been
> exceeded (hitting its TTL), Destinations routes the record to the
> destination resource for every failed invocation for further
> investigation or processing.

To configure destination in Lambda function, Kindly [refer](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-destinations/#:%7E:text=How%20to%20configure%20Destinations)

[image]